# Use csvreader with seqsplit

Tags: csvsimple, seqsplit

How can I use `seqsplit` with `csvreader`? The line breaking isn't working.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{seqsplit}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    columna
    mvhltpeeksavtalwgkvnvdevggealgrllvvypwtqrffesfgdlstpdavmgnpkvkahgkkvlgafsdglahldnlkgtfatlselhcdklhvdpenfrllgnvlvcvlahhfgkeftppvqaayqkvvagvanalahkyh
    \a\very\long\path\a\very\long\path\a\very\long\path\a\very\long\path\a\very\long\path\a\very\long\path\
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
        \csvreader[separator=semicolon, respect all]{data.csv}{columna=\columna}{\seqsplit{\columna}\\}
        
        \vspace{2cm}
        
        \seqsplit{mvhltpeeksavtalwgkvnvdevggealgrllvvypwtqrffesfgdlstpdavmgnpkvkahgkkvlgafsdglahldnlkgtfatlselhcdklhvdpenfrllgnvlvcvlahhfgkeftppvqaayqkvvagvanalahkyh}\\
        \seqsplit{\textbackslash a\textbackslash very\textbackslash long\textbackslash path\textbackslash a\textbackslash very\textbackslash long\textbackslash path\textbackslash a\textbackslash very\textbackslash long\textbackslash path\textbackslash a\textbackslash very\textbackslash long\textbackslash path\textbackslash a\textbackslash very\textbackslash long\textbackslash path\textbackslash a\textbackslash very\textbackslash long\textbackslash path\textbackslash}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of the line breaking issue]

Comment: `\ExpandArgs{o}\seqsplit{\csvcoli}` would work.